# Gradle, commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo doLast!' does nothing

Tags: gradle

I'm reading about [Gradle Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) and created the following `build.gradle`:

```
task startTomcat(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init startTomcat'
} 

task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {

    // on windows:
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init stopTomcat!'
    doLast {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo doLast stopTomcat!'
    }
}
```

When I run `gradlew stopTomcat`, the output looks like this:

```
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:stopTomcat
init stopTomcat!
```

I don't see the line `doLast stopTomcat!` Why can't I execute a command in `doLast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is of type Exec. The `commandLine` method call configures the task by passing the `cmd`, `/c` and `echo init stopTomcat!` to it. This happens in the config phase.

Then the task runs in execution phase and prints:

```
init stopTomcat!
```

Then the `doLast` blocks starts and configures the task, passing `cmd`, `/c` and `echo doLast stopTomcat!` to it. This configuration has no effect as the taks already ran.

To get the second print out, you could do:

```
task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {

    // on windows:
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init stopTomcat!'
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo doLast stopTomcat!'
        }
    }
}
```

This is another way how to invoke the exec task.