# How to run shell script after artifact assemble?

Tags: android, gradle

I want  to run task `wsUpload`, which runs shell script to upload artifact to company server after `assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease` finishes artifact assemble.

Started From this:

```groovy
afterEvaluate {
  task wsUpload(type: Exec, dependsOn: assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease) {
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties");
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
    def WORK_EMAIL = localProperties['WORK_EMAIL']
    commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
    args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
    println("wsUpload start ")
    commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
    //      args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
    println("wsUpload end")
  }

  assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease.doLast {
    println("-------------------------------------")
    println("---------------DO LAST---------------")
    println("-------------------------------------")
    crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease.execute()
  }

}
```

But it runs before assembleRelease finishes.
Then I tried as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057367/1551603)

```groovy
task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties");
  def localProperties = new Properties()
  localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
  def WORK_EMAIL = localProperties['WORK_EMAIL']
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
  args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
  println("wsUpload start ")
  doLast {
    exec {
      commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
      args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
      println("wsUpload end")
    }
  }
}

afterEvaluate {

  assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease.doLast {
    println("-------------------------------------")
    println("---------------DO LAST---------------")
    println("-------------------------------------")
    crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease.execute()
  }
  assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease.doLast {
    wsUpload.execute()
  }
}
```

that left me with `> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

Then I tried to make whole swUpload as doLast

```groovy
task wsUpload(type: Exec) << {
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties");
  def localProperties = new Properties()
  localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
  def WORK_EMAIL = localProperties['WORK_EMAIL']
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
  args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
  println("wsUpload start ")
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
  args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
  println("wsUpload end")
}
```

And got error:

```groovy
Execution failed for task ':app:wsUpload'.
> execCommand == null!
```

Comment: I think this question currently suffers from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271735). What are you actually trying to do? Run a shell script (`ws_upload.sh`) after an artifact is assembled by Gradle (`assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease`)? What are you trying to execute from the command line?

Comment: @mkobit I want to run script after artifact was assembled. The script uploads artifact to company server

Comment: I can identify the tasks `assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease`, `wsUpload` and `crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease`. In what order and conditions should these tasks run?

Comment: @lu.koerfer assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease - first, crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease -second, wsUpload -last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to define a task in a proper way (read about *configuration* vs *execution* in gradle) which will be:

```
task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties");
  def localProperties = new Properties()
  localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
  def WORK_EMAIL = localProperties['WORK_EMAIL']
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
  args [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE, WORK_EMAIL]
}
```

Now you need to define execution order dependencies between tasks - remember not to call `execute()` on a task instance directly never!

I suppose that both `assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease` and `crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease` are dynamic tasks (created after project is evaluated) so it will be sage to define dependencies in `afterEvaluate` block:

```
afterEvaluate {
  crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease.dependsOn assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease
  crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease.mustRunAfter assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease
  wsUpload.dependsOn crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease
  wsUpload.mustRunAfter crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease
}
```

Why both `mustRunAfter` and `dependsOn`? To define not only dependencies but proper execution order as well.
Now you should be able to run `gradle wsUpload` and it should all work well.

If you want to run `assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease` and have artifacts uploaded then `finalizedBy` should be used:

```
afterEvaluate {
   assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease.finalizedBy crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease
   crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease.finalizedBy wsUpload
}
```

Note that since I'm not android developer I can't test it properly - so if it doesn't work, let me know before downvoting ;)

Comment: wsUpload and crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease does not run

Comment: @Yarh, when these tasks do not run? What was gradle command you run?

Comment: I ran `  gradle assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease --stacktrace
`. Artifacts were not uploaded. I if I ran upload tasks separatly (gradle wsUpload or gradle crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease, then artifacts are uploaded, so they are both works

Comment: @Yarh you should run `gradle wsUpload` and artifacts should generated and uploaded - this is how it configured now. If you want to run just `assembleMinAPI16ProdRelease` - `finalizedBy` should be used - will edit my answer.